# brew install python - fails OSX

Tags: python, homebrew, pythonbrew

Im trying to install python through `brew` with:

```
brew install python
```

But get the following error:

```
Stevens-MacBook-Pro :: ~ ‹master*› » brew install python
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/python-2.7.
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.8_2.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring python-2.7.8_2.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Setuptools and Pip have been installed. To update them
  pip install --upgrade setuptools
  pip install --upgrade pip

You can install Python packages with
  pip install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python

.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps` to symlink these to /Applications.
/usr/bin/install_name_tool: object: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python malformed object (unknown load command 10)
Error: Failed to fix install names
The formula built, but you may encounter issues using it or linking other
formula against it.
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/bin/python -ssetup.py --no-user-cfg instal
  using one of the approaches described here:

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall python`
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2: 4626 files, 73M
```

The error messages says the post install fails, and to try installing it again with:

```
brew postinstall python
```

but the error still persists. I also tried `brew linkapps` and it success fully links python but when I run `pip` from the console I get this error:

```
Stevens-MacBook-Pro :: ~ ‹master*› » pip
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Your install_name_tool seems bad. What do `brew doctor` and `brew config` say? If `brew doctor` gives you a warning about install_name_tool, you might look into using a tool like Pacifist to reinstall the system version.

Answer (score 1):

Pyenv is a python version management tool, something like rbenv but for python.

You could easily install and change python version via pyenv easily.

The following shows how to install python with version 2.7.8 through pyenv:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ pyenv install 2.7.8
Downloading Python-2.7.8.tgz...
-> http://yyuu.github.io/pythons/74d70b914da4487aa1d97222b29e9554d042f825f26cb2b93abd20fdda56b557
Installing Python-2.7.8...
Installing setuptools from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py...
Installing pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py...
Installed Python-2.7.8 to /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8
```

as you can see, its very simple.

The command `pyenv install "version"` help you to install a specific versions of python easily and even pip, setuptools are also automatically installed.

I suggest giving [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) a try!!

Comment: Yes, i don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, so i just post an answer. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It doesnt make sense to use pyennv when he's already using homebrew.

Comment: I thought pyenv is still useful when you have the need to work betwwen different versions(py2, py3, pypy). And also pyenv is in brew formula list.