# Bad interpreter: no such file or directory (pyenv or homebrew issue?)

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I'm a Mac 10.9.5 OSX user, and I recently installed pyenv using homebrew. Now I'm getting an issue when I try to use pip. Typing `pip list` produces this error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/python/bin/python2.7: 
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Update: I'm pretty sure it has to do with the shebang line in pip (and also easy_install), but I don't know how to fix it. Right now, it's set to `#!@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/python/bin/python2.7`
Running brew --config, it looks like HOMEBREW_PREFIX = /usr/local
I'm not sure where the error is/what's happening...

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416953/brew-install-python-fails-osx

Comment: Maybe change the shebang to `#!/usr/local/bin/python/bin/python2.7` or, failing that, the same but omitting the first `/bin` from the string.

Comment: Or type `which python` to get the full path to it. Or try `find /usr -name python2.7` Then, wherever you find it, prefix `#!` on the front to make your shebang.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it -- still not entirely sure what the problem was/how it came up, but I unlinked python from homebrew. It fixed both the shebang lines and the error messages.

Comment: Could you please explain _how_ you fixed this, as I am having a related problem.